# make -1 appear as 'unlimited' in <input type='number' />

Tags: html, input, html-input

Can I change the contents of a HTML < input type='number' /> based on the value of the input?

When the input is -1 I want it to display 'unlimited'.

Run the below snippet.

For more context know that I am using Angular 7 and Angular Material.

```html
<p>When the below input value equals -1,<br/> I would like the input to display the text 'unlimited'. <br /> Is this possible? </p>

<input type="number" min="-1" />
```

Comment: Your example has an input of type `number` which cannot contain text (only digits) yet you're asking about an input of type `text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't with an input of type `number` without resorting to trickery.

One way would be to resort to `type="text"` and emulate what `type="number"` already does so conveniently for you (allowing only numeric input, ranges, user-agent-specific UI). Usually turns out pretty messy.

Another way would be to "hide" the number input when its value is -1 and display the text "unlimited" through other means.

I did this here by placing another read-only input field underneath the number input. Other elements would work as well but another input field will give you a consistent look.

```js
let coolInput = document.getElementById('cool-input');

// Not sure if that covers everything
coolInput.addEventListener('keyup', handleInput);
coolInput.addEventListener('change', handleInput);
coolInput.addEventListener('paste', handleInput);

function handleInput() {
  if (coolInput.value == '-1') {
    coolInput.classList.add('unlimited');
  } else {
    coolInput.classList.remove('unlimited');
  }
}
```

```css
form {
  position: relative;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="number"] {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100px;
}
  
#unlimited-input {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
  
#cool-input {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  opacity: 1;
}
  
#cool-input.unlimited {
  background: transparent;
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="unlimited-input" type="text" readonly value="unlimited">
  <input id="cool-input" type="number" min="-1" placeholder="Amount">
</form>
```

([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maryisdead/p53adtL4/))

Works surprisingly well. Haven't tested in IE and iOS though.

Answer (score 0):

This will work-

```js
$("#q").change(()=>{

if($("#q").val()==-1)
$("#w").val("unlimited")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" min="-1" id="q"/>
<input type="text" id="w"/>
```

Comment: He wants to alter the number input though. Not a complimentary second field.

Comment: Number input cannot show "unlimited"! either change the number input to text or the solution which I gave

Comment: I completely agree, good sir. Yet, your answer doesn't address what is asked for.

Comment: The question states that-

Can I change the contents of a HTML < input type='text' />    that's what I did

Comment: If there is no <input type="text">, I don't know how to change something that is not there.